# Erro código 991

Tags: servidor

Alguém sabe o que pode gerar o erro 991? meu site escolaedti não está abrindo, ja tentei entrar em contato com o suporte do meu servidor mas nem eles sabem resolver o problema!

Comment: Até onde sei o código de erro 991 e de Acesso restrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é um erro gerado pela KingHost para problemas com pagamento, já aconteceu com alguns clientes meus.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso , obrigado!

Comment: Se te ajudou marque a pergunta como resolvida

Comment: com certeza ajudou sim, está resolvido, muito obrigado!